# In CiviEvents, on the Events Dashboard, can you change the column widths without doing custom code?

Tags: civievent

Is there a way (without coding) to change the column widths on the Events Calendar view from the Events Dashboard? I am attaching an image of the page I am talking about. Also, I am using the most current version of Wordpress and CiviCRM.
[image]

Comment: Hi Sandy, afaik the only way to do so is via changes to the tpl (template), so yes requires some simple (for those who know) coding

Comment: Thank you so much.